# Post form data to external url

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way to post a form with data to a external url from the controller?

Comment: I solved it using this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636507/redirecting-to-post-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpWebClient of C# to connect to external resource and then post the data.Please refer here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx . I hope prior google/bing would have helped you

Comment: can i redirect webclient class? i would like to post data to a external website and also redirect the user to that website

Comment: Do you want to fill the form data on the website and redirect use to that website ? Or do you want to post the data and then what ever reponse come then you want to redirect to website ? Can you explain more

Comment: it is actually a online payment system. what i want is, that the user enters the amount, and i will create a form with some hidden fields(existing of user input amount + some additional data) in my controller, send that form + the hiddenfields to the external website and also redirect the user to that website, so that he/she can pay through that online payment system.

Answer (score 0):

Let Understand with the help of Example. First Create Object of `HttpClient` then assign Base Address let (https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and data that you want to send in addition with datatype in which data is transferring.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/");//Assign Only Base Addresss

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objDataYouWantTosend), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("questions", content);

var data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<"ClassNameInWhichresponseIsComming">();
```